# How to add div container to array js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

There is a form consisting of two parts. The first part is basic information on the order. The second part of the form consists of the added div of the container. The user can add the second part of the container by clicking on the button. I can not understand how to add the second part of the form to the array in separate positions. 
When you click the submit button,  must create to array:

```
{'user': xxx, 'Phone ': xxx,' voucher': xxx, etc...}
{'user': xxx, 'Phone ': xxx,' voucher': xxx, etc...}
{'user': xxx, 'Phone ': xxx,' voucher': xxx, etc...}
```

This is form two parts. 
User can add another div container

```
<div data-container="set">
                <div data-item="set">
                    <h3>Участник</h3> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>ФИО участника</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control " name="fio" id="fio" value=""> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group"> <label>Телефон участника</label> <input type="text" class="form-control " name="phone[]" id="phone"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group"> <label>E-mail участника</label> <input type="email" class="form-control " name="email[]" id="email"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group"> <label>Номер купона</label> <input type="text" class="form-control " name="voucher[]" id="voucher" > </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="form-messages"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9"><button type="button" data-action="remove" class="btn btn-danger">× Удалить участника</button></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3"><p name="sum[]"></p></div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="1">
                    <input type="text" name="sum[]" readonly> 
                    <input type="text" name="osnovanie[]" id="osnovanie">
                    <input type="text" name="prinadl[]" id="prinadl"><br>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: update question

Comment: thanks to those who responded, found the solution

Comment: please post the solution you found as an answer, or simply delete the question. thanks!

Comment: Added. Sorry, I'm not all rules know )

Answer (score 0):

Solution which helped me with the problem

```
.on('click', '#payment', function(event) {  
   var d = document,
       user_fio = d.getElementsByName('fio[]'),
           user_phone = d.getElementsByName('phone[]'),
       //etc        
   mas = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< user_fio.length; i++){
     mas[i] = {
         'fio': user_fio[i].value,
         'phone': user_phone[i].value,
         //etc
         }
     }
 })
```